# Undo a show/hide div script after browser resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, show-hide

I have a show/hide script that works perfect. But i need this function to not be valid for widths greater than x pixels (in my case, 699px). Is there any way to cancel this in big resolutions so i can show both divs at the same time?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function showHide(d)
{
    var onediv = document.getElementById(d);
    var divs=['content1','overlay'];
    for (var i=0;i<divs.length;i++)
  {
  if (onediv != document.getElementById(divs[i]))
    {
    document.getElementById(divs[i]).style.display='none';
    }
  }
onediv.style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why not just get the width of the browser window and adjust your code based on that width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the screen width and base your code on that.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3qVvH/2/)

```
var w = screen.width;
if(w < 699) {
    //Perform script
    alert("Run script under 699px");
} else {
    alert("Screen width is over 699px, don't perform script");
}
```

Comment: This looks great, but honestly I'm quite new in Javascript. So, do you know how to make both divs visible on the 'else' statement?

Comment: Assuming you are sticking with just javascript, you can do `document.getElementById("id").style.display = '';` for both divs and that should do it.